# Relation between database post, category and category_post (single post with multiple categories)

Tags: mysql

I got 3 table here

1. Post

```
    --------------------
    id | title | content
    --------------------
    1  | lorem | lorem ipsum..
    2  | ipsum | lorem ipsum..
    3  | dolor | lorem ipsum..
```

2. category

```
    -------------
    id | category
    -------------
    1  | cat-1
    2  | cat-2
```

3. post_category

```
    --------------------------
    id | post_id | category_id
    --------------------------
    1  | 1       | 1
    2  | 1       | 2
    3  | 2       | 1
    4  | 3       | 1
    5  | 3       | 2
```

question:

how I can make relation between 3 table above so I can get result in array something like (CMIIW, the point here is the category part display array contain each category)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => lorem
            [content] => lorem ipsum...
            [category] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => cat 1
                            [1] => cat 2
                        )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => ipsum
            [content] => lorem ipsum...
            [category] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => cat 1
                        )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => dolor
            [content] => lorem ipsum...
            [category] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => cat 1
                            [1] => cat 2
                        )
        )
)
```

What I am try is

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM post 
        JOIN post_category
        ON post_category.post_id=post.id
        JOIN category
        ON kategori.id=post_category.category_id
        ORDER BY post.id 
        DESC 
    );
```

but the result its display multiple same post depend on the how much category in the post, I just want to display single post with multiple category

Comment: If the data you are fetching isn't that large, you could query just the posts then iterate each of those and add the categories in a separate query.

Comment: Mysql is a relational database. The query results will always be in a tabular format and can never ever be in the format you expect the result to be. You can use sql to generate json like results, but even then it will not completely look the way you want it to be. Or use php to transform the tabular results into json

Answer (score 0):

found the solutions

```
SELECT p.*, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.id, ':', c.category) SEPARATOR ',') as categories
FROM post p 
JOIN post_category pc 
ON p.id = pc.post_id 
JOIN category c 
ON pc.category_id = c.id 
GROUP BY p.id
```

then just explode "categories"